# Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.14-1.el5.remi

Tags: nginx, yum, php

I try to install PHP-FPM for NGINX then get same errors, with remi repository.
Maybe have version conflate with php-common, How can i fix it.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.mirror.transip.nl
* extras: centos.mirror.transip.nl
* remi: remi-mirror.dedipower.com
* updates: centos.mirror.transip.nl
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.3.14-1.el5.remi set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.14-1.el5.remi for package: php-fpm
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-fpm-5.3.14-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.14-1.el5.remi is needed by package php-fpm-5.3.14-        1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.3.14-1.el5.remi is needed by package php-fpm-        5.3.14-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install/update php-common manually first.

Try this:

```
  rpm -i http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/x86_64/php-common-5.3.14-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

If you get a conflict (say due to an earlier version already installed), use

```
   rpm -i http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/x86_64/php-common-5.3.14-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm --force
```

The old version can be removed without taking its dependencies with it like this

```
 rpm -e --nodeps php-common-5.3.10-1.el5.remi.x86_64
```

Comment: I run into this every time I update my .remi packages as well.  Remi says it's not a bug, though I haven't been able to find what's causing it for me.

Notice above that I'm getting the package from remi's repository, though it won't be found if I query for it through yum.